# Get the calling class in a static method in Python

Tags: python, static-methods

If you have a setup like this:

```
class Animal(object):

    @staticmethod
    def create():
        return Animal()

class Frog(Animal):
    pass
```

You can create animals like `Animal.create()` but if you do `Frog.create()` you also get an `Animal` and not a `Frog`. Is there a way to change the `create()` method to make it create an instance of the class it's being called from?

Comment: Without an understand of what you want this behavior for, can you do the normal way of instantiating an object that inherits from Animal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a typical use case for `classmethod`:

```
class Animal(object):

    @classmethod
    def create(cls):
        return cls()

class Frog(Animal):
    pass

>>> Animal.create()
<Animal object at 0x51fc190>
>>> Frog.create()
<Frog object at 0x51fc610>
```

Comment: yeah, I actually just found out that this was what I needed, thanks anyway!

Comment: Being really bad at programming in general, could you explain why this form of "builder pattern" would be preferable (if it is) to normal inheritance and instantiating the object like this: `frog = Frog()`?

Comment: @limelights In the example it's of no use, but it can be of use if you want to have different ways to instantiate a class, for example, you could have a methods like `create_with_name('Peter')` or `create_with_health('good')`, then those methods can do a lot of setting up for you so you don't have to do it yourself.